# Sampling random values (coordinates) within error range

Tags: r, random, coordinates, gis

In R is there a way to randomly generate values within a set extent from a given point. 
For example if I have coordinates and wish to generate 10 samples within an surrounding error field, can this be done? And if so, can the characteristics of the error field be defined, i.e a square or circle surrounding the original point. Any insight much appreciated.

Example:(WGS84 ESPG:4326)

```
Longitude       Latitude        ErrLong ErrLat
-91.98876953    1.671900034     0.53    1.08 
-91.91790771    1.955003262     0.53    1.08 
-91.91873169    1.961261749     0.53    1.08 
-91.86060333    1.996331811     0.53    1.08 
-91.67115021    1.929548025     0.12    0.12 
-90.67552948    1.850875616     0.12    0.12 
-90.65361023    1.799352288     0.12    0.12 
-92.13287354    0.755102754     0.12    0.12 
-92.13739014    0.783674061     0.12    0.12 
-88.16407776    -4.953748703    0.12    0.12 
-82.51725006    -5.717019081    0.12    0.12 
-82.50763702    -5.706347942    0.12    0.12 
-82.50556183    -5.696153641    0.12    0.12 
-82.50305176    -5.685819626    0.12    0.12 
-82.18003845    -5.623015404    0.53    1.08 
-82.17269897    -5.61870575     0.53    1.08 
-82.16355133    -5.612465382    0.12    0.12
```

For each long/lat I would like 10 randomly generated points within the stated error long/lat (in degrees) from the original location. The random samples should follow a normal distribution and the error field is circular (when lat/long error is equal) and elliptical if not.

Comment: Whilst it's possible to generate data of the type you want, it's impossible to do it in the way you want.  You state you want the the points to both be normally distributed about the given point AND constrained to lie within a given elipse/circle.  You cannot have both: Normally distributed data can lie anywhere on the plane.  (Though it is most likely to lie near the central location.)  You need either to relax your distance requirement or accept a finite distribution for the errors.  If you want to stick with Normal data, you need to specify a covariance matrix to use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So to clarify, you cannot have a normal distribution bound by an extent of impossible values?

Comment: That is correct.  Normally distributed data can take any value between minus infinity and plus infinity (with appropriate generalisations for more than one dimension).  You have several options, including (a) *truncate* your normal distribution to lie within the bounds you specify, (b) allow fully normal data but choose a covariance that means it's very unlikely the generated points will lie outside the bounds you specifiy and (c) choose another distribution of the new points around each of your "centres" that will guarantee the new points meet your restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw from a truncated normal using `msm::rtnorm`.

First, to make things easier, I'd convert the data into long format.

```
dat <- cbind(id=1:nrow(dat), dat)  ## add ID column
names(dat)[-1] <- c("value.lon", "value.lat", "err.lon", "err.lat")  ## better names
## reshape to long
dat.l <- reshape(dat, varying=2:5, direction="long")

dat.l[c(1:2, 15:20), ]
#         id time     value  err
# 1.lon   1  lon -91.988770 0.53
# 2.lon   2  lon -91.917908 0.53
# 15.lon 15  lon -82.180038 0.53
# 16.lon 16  lon -82.172699 0.53
# 1.lat   1  lat   1.671900 1.08
# 2.lat   2  lat   1.955003 1.08
# 3.lat   3  lat   1.961262 1.08
# 4.lat   4  lat   1.996332 1.08
```

Now we use `msm::rtnorm` taking `value` as the `mean` and `err` as the absolute value of a confidence interval as well as the truncation points. To get the list nicely separated into `lon` and `lat` we use `by`.

```
R. <- 1e3
set.seed(42)
res <- by(dat.l, dat.l$time, function(s) 
  sapply(1:nrow(s), function(m, R=R.) {
    x <- as.double(unlist(s[m, -(1:2)]))
    o <- msm::rtnorm(R, x[1], abs((x[1] - x[2]))/1.96, x[1] - x[2], x[1] + x[2])
  }))
```

### Result

The result looks like this (using `R. <- 9`) for sake of brevity:

```
res
# dat.l$time: lat
#          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]      [,8]      [,9]
# [1,] 2.059389 2.854458 1.6480049 1.578799 1.857519 1.933703 1.693664 0.6670599 0.7215978
# [2,] 1.817794 2.435360 0.9810172 1.433516 1.820929 1.844537 1.722964 0.7541789 0.7772778
# [3,] 1.363776 1.499776 2.3656603 2.753531 1.951757 1.911148 1.755089 0.6590040 0.8097877
# [4,] 1.298948 2.903252 1.3621228 2.685882 1.902042 1.850533 1.824228 0.6813604 0.7081114
# [5,] 1.976920 2.017745 2.1074160 2.823800 1.950198 1.785133 1.762703 0.7199149 0.8322832
# [6,] 1.664815 1.664443 1.6482465 1.441457 1.899035 1.807138 1.810606 0.7456769 0.8074188
# [7,] 1.736728 1.494439 2.2212244 1.744971 1.987707 1.835817 1.878827 0.7938251 0.8730894
# [8,] 1.518350 1.541916 1.9629348 1.386725 1.985631 1.833966 1.809587 0.7365271 0.7162421
# [9,] 1.761203 1.667451 1.7359951 2.712280 1.849972 1.965899 1.818468 0.8044030 0.7862688
#          [,10]     [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]     [,15]     [,16]
# [1,] -4.909253 -5.611472 -5.673014 -5.688496 -5.668813 -5.117575 -6.365792
# [2,] -5.024007 -5.691572 -5.601893 -5.752438 -5.771032 -5.795218 -5.392146
# [3,] -4.959013 -5.636268 -5.791113 -5.639635 -5.670745 -5.902636 -4.946774
# [4,] -5.031824 -5.609281 -5.650881 -5.730072 -5.680132 -4.940293 -5.801787
# [5,] -4.984777 -5.774233 -5.807611 -5.711324 -5.801857 -4.618648 -5.821920
# [6,] -4.967051 -5.760783 -5.692485 -5.770230 -5.744132 -6.684446 -6.646540
# [7,] -4.929440 -5.648386 -5.798339 -5.728268 -5.669888 -5.140643 -6.525713
# [8,] -5.031480 -5.609127 -5.646710 -5.579407 -5.787876 -4.587991 -4.771850
# [9,] -5.071611 -5.763129 -5.621419 -5.606133 -5.592998 -6.402314 -4.752597
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#   dat.l$time: lon
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
# [1,] -92.12306 -92.27813 -91.89380 -91.96530 -91.70359 -90.59310 -90.60037 -92.12645
# [2,] -92.08298 -91.73772 -91.74796 -92.32808 -91.57151 -90.55784 -90.69050 -92.11317
# [3,] -91.94673 -91.83403 -91.66878 -91.60644 -91.66306 -90.75866 -90.66495 -92.11768
# [4,] -92.33240 -91.57389 -92.15855 -92.03448 -91.75625 -90.63687 -90.58756 -92.11370
# [5,] -92.17743 -91.58370 -91.82970 -91.44922 -91.72398 -90.75778 -90.62202 -92.15861
# [6,] -92.39499 -91.41112 -92.36735 -92.12330 -91.78401 -90.68612 -90.56967 -92.05469
# [7,] -92.40120 -92.02109 -91.57844 -92.07230 -91.75370 -90.72048 -90.64158 -92.24910
# [8,] -92.08168 -92.10115 -91.98592 -91.33367 -91.58579 -90.60831 -90.65058 -92.17405
# [9,] -91.90599 -91.41466 -91.49233 -91.62150 -91.61410 -90.60368 -90.75319 -92.01950
#           [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]     [,15]     [,16]
# [1,] -92.16208 -88.17055 -82.51806 -82.50556 -82.54585 -82.49562 -81.76493 -81.84638
# [2,] -92.25042 -88.27982 -82.50876 -82.61386 -82.49595 -82.40652 -82.31069 -82.34158
# [3,] -92.20928 -88.08214 -82.55565 -82.43839 -82.48540 -82.55503 -82.38119 -81.84021
# [4,] -92.16342 -88.08550 -82.60778 -82.40032 -82.61227 -82.55625 -82.70171 -82.46027
# [5,] -92.02135 -88.09106 -82.44550 -82.51054 -82.54662 -82.40365 -81.91754 -81.83588
# [6,] -92.02523 -88.22512 -82.58183 -82.43660 -82.51187 -82.47769 -82.56931 -81.86314
# [7,] -92.18523 -88.27581 -82.51715 -82.45542 -82.40686 -82.59609 -81.75961 -82.62096
# [8,] -92.09482 -88.23731 -82.43151 -82.51785 -82.45835 -82.54335 -82.45329 -81.75484
# [9,] -92.07861 -88.18889 -82.60739 -82.46636 -82.48639 -82.41555 -82.11490 -82.59231
```

### Check

Comparison with specified error ranges:

```
lapply(res, function(x) cbind(mean=colMeans(x), err=apply(x, 2, function(x) 
  max(abs(range(x - mean(x))))
)))
# $lat
#             mean       err
#  [1,]  1.6641013 1.0633450
#  [2,]  1.9512697 1.0791531
#  [3,]  1.9664345 1.0766429
#  [4,]  1.9827845 1.0752871
#  [5,]  1.9284320 0.1210392
#  [6,]  1.8525683 0.1213176
#  [7,]  1.8010929 0.1214542
#  [8,]  0.7511818 0.1237103
#  [9,]  0.7871224 0.1228840
# [10,] -4.9542575 0.1203926
# [11,] -5.7174928 0.1200936
# [12,] -5.7064194 0.1198188
# [13,] -5.6925109 0.1234913
# [14,] -5.6876203 0.1217520
# [15,] -5.6436551 1.1001096
# [16,] -5.5955709 1.1015958
# 
# $lon
#            mean       err
#  [1,] -91.99891 0.5390560
#  [2,] -91.91370 0.5327020
#  [3,] -91.92065 0.5312584
#  [4,] -91.84195 0.5476753
#  [5,] -91.67497 0.1229412
#  [6,] -90.67413 0.1212662
#  [7,] -90.64743 0.1261391
#  [8,] -92.13235 0.1204769
#  [9,] -92.13511 0.1214228
# [10,] -88.16036 0.1235441
# [11,] -82.51747 0.1198272
# [12,] -82.50483 0.1225459
# [13,] -82.50418 0.1212391
# [14,] -82.50338 0.1202114
# [15,] -82.16850 0.5410282
# [16,] -82.16828 0.5330564
```

Looks not too bad.

And the **distributions** look like so (using `R. <- 1e3`):

*Longitudes:*

[image: ![enter image description here]

*Latitudes:*

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='Longitude       Latitude        ErrLong ErrLat
-91.98876953    1.671900034     0.53    1.08 
-91.91790771    1.955003262     0.53    1.08 
-91.91873169    1.961261749     0.53    1.08 
-91.86060333    1.996331811     0.53    1.08 
-91.67115021    1.929548025     0.12    0.12 
-90.67552948    1.850875616     0.12    0.12 
-90.65361023    1.799352288     0.12    0.12 
-92.13287354    0.755102754     0.12    0.12 
-92.13739014    0.783674061     0.12    0.12 
-88.16407776    -4.953748703    0.12    0.12 
-82.51725006    -5.717019081    0.12    0.12 
-82.50763702    -5.706347942    0.12    0.12 
-82.50556183    -5.696153641    0.12    0.12 
-82.50305176    -5.685819626    0.12    0.12 
-82.18003845    -5.623015404    0.53    1.08 
-82.17269897    -5.61870575     0.53    1.08')
```

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated.